# How to display only the last 2 entries tag, or only the first 2 entries tag on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-thesis-theme

Good afternoon! There was a task to display only the last 2 tag this record, and only 2 of the first tag of this record. How to do it ? I would be very grateful, I put the picture of what I mean

[image: the tags post]